# Не подключаются CSS and JS в Gulp

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp4

Ребят, нужна помощь!
Проблема вот в чем, сейчас осваиваю Gulp и есть небольшие трудности.
 Мой `gulpfile.js` работает без ошибок(по крайне мере в консоле проходит все гладко), но когда после сборки проекта, открывается окно с сайтом, он отображается без `CSS` и `JS`
И если открыть в google открыть панель с просмотром кода, то там тоже ничего нет
В чем может быть проблема?
Прилагаю скрин сборки в редакторе и скрин консоли, а так же сам `gulpfile.js` и `package.json`.
[image: Скрин консоли выполнения команды <code>gulp default</code>]
[image: Скрин директории после сборки]

Пример кода `gulpfile.js`

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync").create(),
    del = require('del'),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

var path = {
    build: {
        html: 'build/',
        js: 'build/js/',
        css: 'build/css/',
        img: 'build/img/',
        fonts: 'build/fonts/'
    },
    src: {
        html: 'src/*.html',
        js: 'src/js/main.js',
        style: 'src/style/main.scss',
        img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    watch: {
        html: 'src/**/*.html',
        js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
        style: 'src/style/**/*.scss',
        img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    clean: './build'
};

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
                browserSync.init({
                    server: {
                        baseDir: './build',
                        index: 'index.html'
                    },
                    port: 3000,
                    open: true
                });
            });

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del('build');
});

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.js)
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.style)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            sourceMap: true,
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(prefixer())
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('image:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.img)
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()],
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
});

gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel(
    'html:build',
    'js:build',
    'style:build',
    'fonts:build',
    'image:build'
));


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('html:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.style], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('js:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('image:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('fonts:build');
    });
});


gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('build', 'watch', 'browserSync'))

);
```

Мой `package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "gulp": "gulp"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-debug": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-rigger": "^0.5.8",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#v4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: а в html вы подключили main.css ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Он разве не должен сам это делать и выводить?!

Comment: нет конечно ...вы что ? делаете разметку подключаете css js и открываете хоть от fil:/// хоть от сервера

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Я посмотрел несколько скринкастов и статей перечитал, я думал это одна из фишек сбощика

Comment: они там не показывают как размечают страницу - не тратят время...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский а вы пользуетесь Gulp?

Comment: конечно - gulp создаст файл и директорию а вот css js вы подключаете из этих директоий

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Понял, спасибо! Несколько часов не мог понять в чем проблема